# Use pytest to test and grade student code

Tags: python, pytest

Say I want to grade some student python code using tests, something like (this is pseudo-code I wish I could write):

```
code = __import__("student_code")  # Import the code to be tested 

grade = 100
for test in all_tests():           # Loop over the tests that were gathered

    good = perform(test, code)     # Perform the test individually on the code
    if not good:                   # Do something if the code gives the wrong result
        grade -= 1
```

For that, I would like to use `pytest` (easy to write good tests), but there are many things I don't know how to do:

- how to run tests on *external* code? (here the `code` imported from student's code)
- how to list all the tests available? (here `all_tests()`)
- how to run them individually on code? (here `perform(test, code)`)

I couldn't find anything related to this user-case (`pytest.main()` does not seem to do the trick anyhow...)

I hope you see my point, cheers!

**EDIT**

I finally found how to perform my 1st point (apply tests on external code). In the repository where you want to perform the tests, generate a `conftest.py` file with:

```
import imp                      # Import standard library
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    """Add a custom command-line option to py.test."""

    parser.addoption("--module", help="Code file to be tested.")

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def module(request):
    """Import code specified with the command-line custom option '--module'."""

    codename = request.config.getoption("--module")

    # Import module (standard __import__ does not support import by filename)
    try:
        code = imp.load_source('code', codename)
    except Exception as err:
        print "ERROR while importing {!r}".format(codename)
        raise

    return code
```

Then, gather your tests in a `tests.py` file, using the `module` fixture:

```
def test_sample(module):

    assert module.add(1, 2) == 3
```

Finally, run the tests with `py.test tests.py --module student.py`.

I'm still working on points 2 and 3.

**EDIT 2**

I uploaded my (incomplete) take at this question:

https://gitlab.in2p3.fr/ycopin/pyTestExam

Help & contributions are welcome!

Comment: Where did you get the function `perform` from?

Comment: Just a pointer: it's frowned upon to 1) not show any own effort (which I can understand here though), and 2) to ask multiple questions at once

Comment: I'm sure you know this, but be careful about running untrusted code.  An evil student might decide it's a great idea to do `from os.path import expanduser; import shutil; shutil.rmtree(expanduser('~'))`.

Comment: Or they could go even simpler and do `import os; os.system('rm -rf ~/*')`

Answer (score 0):

Very cool and interesting project.  It's difficult to answer without knowing more.

Basically you should be able to do this by writing a [custom plugin](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#builtin-plugins).  Probably something you could place in a `conftest.py` in a test or project folder with your unittest subfolder and a subfolder for each student.

Probably would want to write two plugins:

- One to allow weighting of tests (e.g. test_foo_10 and and test_bar_5) and calculation of final grade (e.g. 490/520) (teamcity-messages is an example that uses the [same hooks](http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#pytest-hook-reference))
- Another to allow distribution of test to separate processes. ([xdist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-xdist) as an example)

I know this is not a very complete answer but I wanted to at least point out the last point.  Since there would be a very high probability that students would be using overlapping module names, they would clash in a pytest world where tests are collected first and then run in a process that would attempt to not re-import modules with a common name.

Even if you attempt to control for that, you will eventually have a student manipulate the global namespace in a sloppy way that could cause another students code to fail.  You will, for that reason, need either a bash script to run each students file or a plugin that would run them in separate processes.

Make this use case a graded take-home exam and see what they come up with :-) ... naaah ... but you could ;-)

Comment: I understand your second item, but I did have in mind to perform the grading one at a time (and e.g. rely on an external bash script to loop over students).  I did not think of running potentially "untrusted code" before, because 1. my students are trustable 2. they are 1st year in python... Yet, it could be interesting indeed to execute tests in a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with something like this (whre it is assument that the `sum` function is the student code):

```
import unittest

score = 0

class TestAndGrade(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_correctness(self):
    
        self.assertEqual(sum([2,2]), 4)

        global score; score += 6 # Increase score  


    def test_edge_cases(self):

        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            sum([2,'hello'])
    
        global score; score += 1 # Increase score


    # Print the score
    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        global score
        print('\n\n-------------')
        print('| Score: {} |'.format(score))
        print('-------------\n')


# Run the tests
unittest.main()
```